# D3 - Chart width rounded edges

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

currently have a problem with the chart when the value data is smaller, I have an 'ear' effect can you help me please whit this?

[image: This is the result that I have]

This is the code that I'm using:

```
const rx = 30;
          const ry = 30;
          svg
            .selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
              return x(d.key);
            })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("y", function (d) {
              return y(d.value);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
              return height - y(d.value);
            })
            .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
            .attr(
              "d",
              (item) => `
        M${x(item.key)},${y(item.value) + ry}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${-ry}
        h${x.bandwidth() - 2 * rx}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${ry}
        v${height - y(item.value) - ry}
        h${-x.bandwidth()}Z
      `
            )
```

I have tried many things but works :|

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with **Quadratic Bezier** path:

```js
const roundedBarPath = (centerX, bottomY, width, height) => {
  const radius = Math.min(width/2, height/2);
  return `
  M ${centerX - width/2}, ${bottomY} 
  V ${bottomY - height + radius}
  Q ${centerX - width/2},${bottomY - height} 
  ${centerX - width/2 + radius},${bottomY - height}
  H ${centerX + width/2 - radius}
  Q ${centerX + width/2},${bottomY - height}
  ${centerX + width/2},${bottomY - height + radius}
  V ${bottomY} Z`;
}

const path1 = roundedBarPath(50,100,30,80);
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path').attr('d', path1).style('fill', 'blue');
  
const path2 = roundedBarPath(100,100,30,20);
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path').attr('d', path2).style('fill', 'blue');  
  
const path3 = roundedBarPath(150,100,30,3);
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path').attr('d', path3).style('fill', 'blue');    
  
const path4 = roundedBarPath(200,100,30,60);
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path').attr('d', path4).style('fill', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="150">
</svg>
```